# Error when installing Hyperledger Composer pre-requisites on Ubuntu Bionic

Tags: ubuntu, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to install Hyperledger Composer pre-requisites on Ubuntu according to [this instruction](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/installing/installing-prereqs.html), but I get an error: Ubuntu bionic is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

It's more a statement of what version of ubuntu the helper script `prereqs-ubuntu.sh` will work with.

You should be able to use bionic just you will have to make sure you have the right pre-requisites yourself rather than being able to use the helper script

Support for bionic via the script will be added at some point soon, along with updating the docs to include that version as being a version that can be used.